# Why does my smart contract tokens not show up in MyEtherWallet or MetaMask?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, myetherwallet, metamask

I have deployed a very basic smart contract to the Rinkeby test network. The contract's address is 0xb145b6d8757b40ac80b5fe2a98ab6c8450a54585. I have made transactions to it using MetaMask, and they show up on Etherscan, for instance this: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x63802d405b809434a34050176c7050549e323b75443b0ae8096ab81985f18b9f . The transaction also shows as "confirmed" in MetaMask. I am also able to confirm that my MetaMask account has tokens using `truffle console` and checking the account address's balance of tokens.

However, even though I add the token in MetaMask with contract address=0xb145b6d8757b40ac80b5fe2a98ab6c8450a54585, symbol=BRR and decimals=18, they don't show up in MetaMask. The same thing happens if I "watch token" in MyEtherWallet. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I swapped the old pundix npxs for ethereum in my trust wallet and it says successful for the smart contract but the ethereum didn’t show up it still shows npxs token. it says $0 for the value but I swapped 1.374 million npxs and it shows ethereum was at $2k when I did this. How do I get the tokens?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to give Metamask the address of the token itself, not the address of the contract that created the token, like you did. I made the same mistake myself.

Comment: would you mind explaining where one can find `token address`, please?  tks

Comment: the token address is generated when you deploy the contract, as far as i can remember.

Answer (score 0):

I have found why i could NOT see my tokens in my metamask wallet,

1) Login into My Ether Wallet & Access MetaMask wallet

2) CLICK  ethplorer.io  under TOKEN BALANCES (The token contract address used previously from etherscan.io, to create token wallet was INVALID)

3) Search & Copy contract address from  ethplorer.io

4) Search & Copy number of token decimals from etherscan.io

5) Add custom token wallet in MEW or MetaMask

6) Refresh and balances of tokens should show

Thank you